# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pregnancies'

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror, naivebayes

```
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open('diabetes.csv'))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]
    return dataset
```

I'm trying to implement Naive-Bayes but its giving me this error even though I've manually changed the type of each column to float.
it's still giving me error.

Above is the function to convert.

Comment: Without any information on the content in `dataset[i]`, we cant help you. Print out the content in `dataset[i]`, and check if you have items that cannot be converted to float (e.g. string of alphabets)

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
df.dtypes
Pregnancies                   int64
Glucose                       int64
BloodPressure                 int64
SkinThickness                 int64
Insulin                       int64
BMI                         float64
DiabetesPedigreeFunction    float64
Age                           int64
Outcome                       int64
dtype: object

Comment: there's no strings it just takes the name of the first column and says it can not be converted to float. it's the pima-diabetes dataset. pregnancies is the name of first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValueError` is because the code is trying to cast (convert) the items in the CSV header row, which are strings, to floats.  You could just skip the first row of the CSV file, for example:

```
for i in range(1, len(dataset)): # specifying 1 here will skip the first row
    dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]
```

Note: that would leave the first item in `dataset` as the headers (`str`).

Personally, I'd use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which has a `read_csv()` method, which will load the data directly into a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
```

This will give you a `dataframe` though, not a list of lists.  If you really want a list of lists, you could use `dataset.values.tolist()`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert non-numeric values to floats

```
for a column in the dataframe. columns:  
    dataframe[column] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe[column], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The original question did not include any mention of pandas. Are you sure you didn't accidentally reply to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60972308/1519716)?